# Find all rows with Null value(s) in a specific column(s) in Big Query

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Is there a way to improve the following? I need to count all rows with `NULL` value(s) in a specific column.

```sql
SELECT
  SUM(IF(column1 IS NULL, 1, 0)) AS column1, 
  SUM(IF(column2 IS NULL, 1, 0)) AS column2
FROM 
  `dataset.table`;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the options:

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT
  COUNTIF(column1 IS NULL) AS column1,
  COUNTIF(column2 IS NULL) AS column2
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

Or (just to have few options for you):

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT
  COUNT(1) - COUNT(column1) AS column1,
  COUNT(1) - COUNT(column2) AS column2
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```